# importance of each predictor in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, chi-squared-test

I recently read a paper made a logistic regression and used a table like this to summarise the model:

```
data.frame(predictors = c("drat", "mpg"), "chi squared statistic" = c("x", "x"), "p-value" = c("x", "x"))

  predictors chi.squared.statistic p.value
1       drat                     x       x
2        mpg                     x       x
```

The data.frame presented the chi-squared and p value (the x's) for each predictor in the logistic regression model, and thus allowed to see at a glance which predictors were most important.

I have made this logistic regression model:

```
mtcars_log_reg <- glm(vs ~ drat + mpg, mtcars, family = "binomial")
```

How can I fill in the x's for the above table using R code?

Answer (score 5):

## Doing the chi-square test in R

Well, it’s very easy to *do*:

```
> drop1(mtcars_log_reg, test = "LRT") # or test = "Chisq"

Single term deletions

Model:
vs ~ drat + mpg
       Df Deviance    AIC     LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
<none>      25.351 31.351                      
drat    1   25.533 29.533  0.1825 0.6692659    
mpg     1   37.159 41.159 11.8079 0.0005898 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

But it doesn’t answer the question of which predictors are the ‘most important’ (which is in general a very difficult question to answer, and it may not even be a *meaningful* question).

Note that usually the results are very similar to the Wald tests you get with `summary()`:

```
> summary(mtcars_log_reg)

Call:
glm(formula = vs ~ drat + mpg, family = "binomial", data = mtcars)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.1297  -0.5415  -0.1981   0.6142   1.8299  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -7.7555     4.0002  -1.939   0.0525 .
drat         -0.5619     1.3327  -0.422   0.6733  
mpg           0.4770     0.2005   2.380   0.0173 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
```

## What are we really doing here?

To keep the answer more statistical and less about R, let me explain what we are doing here. For each variable `var`, we are comparing a logistic model containing all predictors with a similar model containing all variables *except* `var`. The two models are nested, so we can use a likelihood ratio test (LRT).

Basically, twice the difference in log likelihood between the two models will have an approximate chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the difference in degrees in freedom for the two models. For the variable `mpg`, we have

```
# Fit the full and simplified models
> mod.full = glm(vs ~ drat + mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial)
> mod.simple = glm(vs ~ drat, data = mtcars, family = binomial)

# Extract the log likelihood values for each model
> ( ll.full = logLik(mod.full) )
'log Lik.' -12.67544 (df=3)
> ( ll.simple = logLik(mod.simple) )
'log Lik.' -18.5794 (df=2)

# Calculate the likelihood ratio test statistic
> ( lrt.stat = c(2*(ll.full - ll.simple)) )
[1] 11.80793

# Calculate the P-value
> pchisq(lrt.stat, df = 3-2, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.0005897904
```

which are the same test statistics and P-values as above (with a few extra digits shown).

Note that when the predictors are continuous, the difference in degrees of freedom is always 1, but when they are factors (categorical variables), the difference correspond to the number of extra dummy variables (parameter estimates in the R output) used in the full model.